# pointers to vectors as class members pointers to vectors in functions

Tags: class, c++11, vector, graph, member

I'm a noob. Using C++ in Clion

I'm building a graph of N random nodes on a Cartesian plane

I have a simple type, node (just a point)  (int x, int y)
node pt(x,y)

I have a vector of N randomly generated unique points (would this be considered ordered points btw?)
vector NodeList(N);

I have a class Graph (Incomplete) which has a function GenNodelist which I have tested as a standalone program.   I had a hell of a time just getting the constructor to build without compile error.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #ifndef DIJKSTRA_GRAPH_H
    #define DIJKSTRA_GRAPH_H

    using namespace std;

    class Graph {

        private:
            int x;
            int y;
            vector<int> NodeList;
            int *np;
     public:

     //constructor
   x(x),y(y),NodeList(),np(){}


    void GenNodeList(vector<int> NL(), int &np) {x,y,NodeList, &np; }

    void GenNodeList(vector<int> *NL, int *p);

    };


    #endif //DIJKSTRA_GRAPH_H


void Graph::GenNodeList(vector<int>* NL, int* p) {
                             .
                             .
 }                            .
...  code that builds and has been quasi tested
```

So everything builds and there's a "hello world" main program in the project. The 2 classes, (node & Graph:  2 headers and 2 cpp files) along with the main "hello world" build and run.  Now from main() I wan to call the call the GenNode function from main.  I just want to pass a pointer and have the list generate and sit in memory UN-mutable. right now.  I'll build the graph off of this later.  When I try to call the function nothing works. How can I build this list and access it from main() and Graph()?

```
main(){
    vector<int> NL(N);
    int *np;

    Graph::GenNodeList( NL, np);
}
```

Can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: The code you provided is nowhere near close to compiling. Please create an actual [mcve]

Comment: If it's minimal it won't compile.  Of course this doesn't compile.

Comment: I don't think you understand the meaning of [mcve] - without one we cannot help you. Also the code you provided fails to compile due to many more reasons than being "minimal"

Comment: My code compiles just fine with the exception of the function call in main()

Comment: I can run everything in this project up to the function call in main.  There is no minimal, complete verifiable example so I guess you can't help me.

Comment: I'm going to try to work with smart pointers  of which I know nothing, but the definition seems to fit and it seems like a good direction in which to look.  It would have been a good suggestion.  I built this whole project out of complete minimal and verifiable pieces.  I don't need anyone to verify my minimal, complete examples.  There is more than sufficient material out there to do it myself.

Comment: It is direction in the context of the greater project where difficulty lies.  I need to create and then access this vector of immutable objects from several places.  HTF am I to present this problem in a minimal , complete and verifiable example of code?

Comment: @Pasqualino31 This is "HTF" you can present your problem in a minimal, complete and verifiable example of code: `void addOne(vector<int>* v) { v.push_back(1); } int main() { vector<int> vec; addOne(vec); cout << vec[0]; }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass objects to functions in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139224/how-to-pass-objects-to-functions-in-c)

Comment: `main()` is not legal C++. Please write `int main()` and also use compiler flags to enable common warnings (`-Wall -Werrror -pedantic` is a good set).

Comment: I'm also learning how to use GitHub and made a repository for this project.  Right now is one big source file Which generates the N, random and unique nodes and then I make a graph by assigning random connections and use the distance the connected nodes as the edge weight.  The assignment requires several classes with some particular functions, so I need to break up the big sloppy mess into an elegant C++ project.  This is where I'm running into problems.  Anyone who wants to laugh at my stuff can go here.  https://github.com/Pasqualino31/Dijkstra

Comment: I have no clue how to set compiler flags.

Answer (score 0):

This incomplete piece of code

```
Graph::GenNodeList( NL, np);
```

is ill-formed because that method is not static. You have to access instance of class Graph for non-static members. Nothing about oop here, just language's rules.

Answer (score 0):

```
Graph():   x(x),y(y),NodeList(),np(){}

static void GenNodeList(vector<node>* NL, node* np);

void Graph::GenNodeList(vector<node>* NL, node* p) {

int main() {
    vector<node> NL(N);
    vector<node>* NList;
    node *np = nullptr;

    NList = &NL;

    Graph::GenNodeList(NList,np);

return 0;
```

https://github.com/Pasqualino31/Dijkstra/tree/Pasqualino31-patch-2